# Convert existing magento website compatible to mobile

Tags: mobile

Please suggest some tutorials for converting existing magento website to mobile website.

Answer (score 1):

To show you page on smaller screen you need to use size adaptive theme. Such technology is called "responsive". Easiest way to get on the responsive bandwagon is to use some pre-existing commercial (or free) theme and modify it to suit your needs. Such themes are nowadays dirt cheap and can be found from several theme-repositories.

If you feel like building theme yourself, then the latest Magento CE (1.9.0.1) comes with pre-installed RWD theme. While it has its own number of issues, it's very good starting point to learn how to build responsive theme. Be warned however, that it's going to take considerable effort.

Comment: Hi Pronto, Means by changing the theme i can make by magento website compatible to mobile browser right ? Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Well, yes. Theme is more or less your presentation layer. Either updating it (by taking hints from RWD) or replacing it with already responsive theme is pretty much all you need to make your site mobile browser compatible.

Comment: Hello Pronto , One more question Can we develop native android application in magento . Can you suggest me some tutorials for developing native android mobile application in magento and connect that application with magento website database.

Comment: Building apps is SO 2010. However, Magento provides service to build shopping app for you, but I think its more or less deprecated.

If you want to build an app for Magento, then you should probably investigate Web Service API-s:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

As Pronto points out, the RWD theme from the recent Magento v1.9 should be the way to go to build a Magento responsive theme.

If your goal is to build a native app (as you say in a comment), then you should take a look at both the REST and SOAP APIs. I must warn that it won't be easy, though. Many inconsistencies and incomplete stuff show how little prepared Magento is for mobile development.

You could also take a look at [MeetsIO](http://www.meets.io), an open-source framework for both Android and iOS, which makes connection to Magento much easier.